# JVM exception occured:Need Bluetooth permission: Neither user 10258 not current process has android.permission.Bluetooth python jnius?

Tags: java, python, bluetooth, jvm, kivy

I want to create Bluetooth app, I have `.apk` file with this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.uix.label import Label


def get_socket_stream(name):
    paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
    socket = None
    for device in paired_devices:
        if device.getName() == name:
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            recv_stream = socket.getInputStream()
            send_stream = socket.getOutputStream()
            break
    socket.connect()
    return recv_stream, send_stream


class Bluetooth():
    def __init__(nameOfDevice):
        self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = get_socket_stream(nameOfDevice)

    def send(self, cmd):
        self.send_stream.write('{}\n'.format(cmd))
        self.send_stream.flush()

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothDevice, BluetoothSocket, UUID
        self.fl = FloatLayout()
        try:
            BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
            BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
            BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
            UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')
            get_socket_stream('DESKTOP-I2CNCPQ')
            self.fl.add_widget(Label(text='no errors', pos=(0, 0), font_size=(40)))
       except Exception as error:
           self.fl.add_widget(Label(text=str(error), pos=(0, 0), font_size=(20)))
       return self.fl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

And I get error:

```
JVM exception occured:Need Bluetooth permission: Neither user 10258 not current process has android.permission.Bluetooth
```

How can I fix it? I didn't find the answer how to fix it in python, I hope you help me.............................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have missing permissions you have to add them in the .p4a file or via command line

```
--permission BLUETOOTH
```

will help. 
Probably you need

```
--permission BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

as well.

If you use buildozer you have to add

```
 android.permissions = BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,BLUETOOTH
```

in buildozer.spec

Comment: I created `main.p4a` file and enter `--permission BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'` but I get same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's only ".p4a" when you create thepackage with python4android ... when you create with another package manager please specify

Comment: I created `.apk` file with buildozer

Comment: edited my answer with what I've found for buildozer